# Artifact Resolution Source in Gradle

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, ivy

I am trying to find a way to determine where an artifact "came from" in gradle/groovy.

I have a set of artifacts that were resolved from a custom Ivy repository, however, I need to build a classpath that will be used at runtime to point at that custom Ivy repository location.  (The custom Ivy repository is actually a network drive where our software is distributed)

The problem is that I cannot figure out a way to intercept the initial resolution from the custom repository...and I also do not know whether I can force a resolution from the network somehow so I can gather the data I need.

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this?

Comment: I don't think that Gradle provides this information. You can force resolution with `--refresh-dependencies`.

Comment: is there any way to force refresh inside code or the script?

Comment: Try `gradle.startParameter.refreshDependencies = true`.